# Javascript not changing iframe source after first change

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that has an Iframe with the source of `foo.php`.

I also have 5 links on my page that when clicked trigger a javascript function to change the source. The only issue is that after I click on one link and it changes the iframe, the next time I click on a link it doesn't change anymore.

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
function changeSource(newSource) {
    parent.sec1.document.location=newSource;
}
</script>
```

and here is the html:

```
<a href="#calandar" onclick="changeSource('http://www.example.com/view.php')">Calandar</a><br />
<a href="#facebook" onclick="changeSource('http://www.facebook.com')">Facebook</a><br />
<a href="#gmail" onclick="changeSource('http://www.gmail.com')">Gmail</a><br />
<a href="#reddit" onclick="changeSource('http://www.reddit.com')">Reddit</a><br />
<a href="#twitter" onclick="changeSource('http://www.twitter.com')">Twitter</a><br />
</div>

<div id="sec1">
<iframe src="view.php" name="meat" width="100%" height="75%" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, try adding id to that iframe, and do:

```
function changeSource(newSource) {
  document.getElementById('yourIframeId').src = newSource;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! I will accept your answer when the time limit finishes. But, thank you so so so much!

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. We are here to share and help.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function changeSource(newSource) {
    document.getElementById('my-iframe').src=newSource;
}
</script>
...
...
...
<iframe src="view.php" id='my-iframe' width="100%" height="75%" ></iframe>
```